# User nil when uploading image with tinymce

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    

has_attached_file :file

def user_name
  @user.name
end

belongs_to :user

end
```

I can create a new post (without images) no problem. When I try to insert an image however, I get an `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error. If I take out `user_name`, image uploads work.

The form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "tinymce textarea" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the error:

```
Processing by TinymceAssetsController#create as HTML
...
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 134ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
app/models/post.rb:14:in `user_name'
app/controllers/tinymce_assets_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

and heres the tinymce controller:

```
class TinymceAssetsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json

def create
 geometry = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file params[:file]
 question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)
 @user = User.find(question.user_id)

 render json: {
   image: {
     url:    question.file.url,
     height: geometry.height.to_i,
     width:  geometry.width.to_i
   }
 }, layout: false, content_type: "text/html"

 end
end
```

How do access `user` when uploading images?

Comment: without seeing the form I can't say for sure, but I can say that the object you are calling `name` on is nil. So look at your form and figure out what object there is nil. --edit maybe try `@user.name`

Comment: Could you paste in the relevant controller action and the form?

Comment: Edited. I'm using tinymce for the image upload so I have a seperate controller for image uploads. I'll paste the full error.

Comment: I changed around the question. Figured its not a friendly_id problem but a tinymce one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a tinyMCE issue.  Your controller is wrong:

```
question = Question.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)
 @user = User.find(question.user_id)
```

You need to do something like this:

```
question = current_user.questions.create params.permit(:file, :alt, :hint)
```

or if you are going to create a question directly, set the user from somewhere.  What you've written creates a Question with 3 parameters: file, alt and hit but doesn't set the user.

Comment: I'd also recommend moving the `params.permit` to a private method so that its reusable and cleaner. [link](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an instance of the `User` class is defined, so when you are referencing it, rails tells you it's a null object.

`@user = User.find(@post.user_id)`

Comment: I'm unsure where to put this line though. I edited the question with my attempt  but still no luck.

Comment: User.find(@post.user_id).name is nil and so is @user = User.find(@post.user_id)

Comment: Ah I see that the tiny_mce controller sets the user instance. So it looks like you are getting a nil object when you call@user = User.find(question.user_id). I would drop debugger right after that line and find out what the value of @user is. If nil, question.user_id is likely nil as well. When you do Question.create does the model receive a user id?

Comment: Yeah question.user_id is nil as well. And no, no user_id after Question.create. I'm unsure what you mean by tinymce sets the user instance.